# highcharts get data by JSON?

Tags: jquery, json, highcharts

I want to pass data to highcharts by getJSON method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var chart;
    $(document).ready(function(){
$("#datepicker1").datepicker({showOn: 'button', buttonImage: 'css/base/images   /calendar.gif', buttonImageOnly: true,dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"});
  });
function draw_chart(){`
   var url="http://localhost/handle_data.php?start=2012-12-30&end=2013-01-04";
    chart=new Highcharts.Chart({});

$.getJSON(url,function(data1){
 var options={
    chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
    type: 'line'
        },

        xAxis:{
    type: 'datetime'

   },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'test'
            }

        }, 
        series:[{
           data:data1.result[0].dayactivity,
           name: "name"
       }]

};
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
}

</script>
</head>

<body>

<div >  
<input type="text" id="datepicker1" name="date1" onchange='draw_chart()' >
</div>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

the value of `data1.result[0].dayactivity` is:

```
[[1356796800,0.0],[1356883200,16.1],[1356969600,0.0],[1357056000,0.0],[1357142400,15.0]],
```

when i put this value directly to `options.series[0].data`, it works, but when i pass it throuth getJSON, it does not. The chart is empty. It seems that it executes `var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);` first. How can i solve this? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move the creation of the `Chart` within the `success` callback of `$.getJSON();` You only have to instantiate and create the `Chart` once and that will be within the callback function.

```
function draw_chart() {
    var url="http://localhost/handle_data.php?start=2012-12-30&end=2013-01-04";
    $.getJSON(url,
        function(data1){
            /** Declare options after success callback. */
            var options={
                chart: {
                     renderTo: 'container',
                     type: 'line'
                },
                xAxis:{
                     type: 'datetime'
                },
                yAxis: {
                     title: { text: 'test'}
                }, 
                series:[{
                    data:data1.result[0].dayactivity,
                    name: "name"
                }]
           };

           /** Create a chart instance and pass options. */
           var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
       }
    );
}
```

Comment: OP's code is same, not well formated, problem is that he run `new Highcharts.Chart({});` too early

Comment: Yes, it is same code. How to make it run new Highcharts.Chart({}) a bit late? if i write it outside of $.getJSON, the options variable will not be defined. Any idea?

Comment: `options` is defined within the callback function so it should work if you run chart like I have it above.

Answer (score 0):

You initialised highcharts, before get data, this is fixed script, I commented changed lines.

```
var chart;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#datepicker1").datepicker({
        showOn: 'button',
        buttonImage: 'css/base/images   /calendar.gif',
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
    });
});

function draw_chart() {
    var url = "http://localhost/handle_data.php?start=2012-12-30&end=2013-01-04";
//    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({}); //PROBLEM ONE - empty initialisation 

    $.getJSON(url, function (data1) {
        var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'line'
            },

            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime'

            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'test'
                }

            },
            series: [{
                data: data1.result[0].dayactivity,
                name: "name"
            }]

        };
        //var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options); // removed var here, as it looks you want it to be global
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });
}
draw_chart();
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/2KCfH/) without json, but you can see problem

Comment: ok. thanks eicto, i found the problem, it is not because of the var. i add eval at series: [{
                data: eval(data1.result[0].dayactivity),
                name: "name"
            }]. Now it works!

Comment: if I wasnt married, I'd kiss you and ask you to marry me ! I was looking for solution why data do not appear on my chart, EVAL was the answer. Thank you thank you thank you :)

Comment: @user1611237 : Thanks at least you mention solution in comment. It solves my problem as well. I think you should add this as a answer :)