# How to extract data fron json to javascript highchart?

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

this is part of my json file and the data contain this useless symbol **''\''** ...:

```
    "{\"0\":{\"index\":23,\"indicator\":\"ClassC Time\",\"month\":201611,\"ww\":201648,\"test_time\":0.0,\"p\":48.0,\"Product\":\"RB\"},\"1\":{\"index\":24,\"indicator\":\"ClassC\",\"month\":201612,\"ww\":201649,\"test_time\":47.48,\"p\":48.0,\"Product\":\"RB\"}
```

below is my javascript code to create highchart:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
var options = {
  chart: {type: 'line',height: 250,},
  title: {text: 'Sky'},
  subtitle: {text: 'May 11, 2016'},
  xAxis: {categories: ['9:30 am', '10:00 am', '10:30 am', '11:00am', '11:30 am', '12:00 pm','12:30 pm', '1:00 pm', '1:30 pm', '2:00 pm', '2:30 pm','3:00 pm', '3:30 pm', '4:00 pm'],
  labels: {step: 3}},
  legend: {enabled: false},
  series: [{
    name: 'Nasdaq',
    color: '#4572A7',
    data: [2606.01, 2622.08, 2636.03, 2637.78, 2639.15, 2637.09,
      2633.38, 2632.23, 2632.33, 2632.59, 2630.34, 2626.89, 2624.59, 2615.98
    ]}]};$('#container').highcharts(options);});</script>
```

How can get used **$getJSON** to include in my javascript? I try to follow [highcharts get data by JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14658104/highcharts-get-data-by-json) but I dunno why my html page is a blank page, not able see any chart...

Comment: JSON.parse() that string chunk

Comment: Sorry  I still not understand, can you share me more?

Comment: Open JS console and check the errors. If you have any, then resolve them first. Regarding JSON, I suggest to follow [this tutorial](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/custom-preprocessing#3). First start with the same JSON as in the example, then change the JSON to your and let us know about the results :)

Comment: may I know more about JS console?

Comment: hit f12 to open JS console if you are using chrome browser

Answer (score 0):

Try this in you browser control you can see the parsed result then use it in you project

```
JSON.parse("{\"0\":{\"index\":23,\"indicator\":\"ClassC Time\",\"month\":201611,\"ww\":201648,\"test_time\":0.0,\"p\":48.0,\"Product\":\"RB\"},\"1\":{\"index\":24,\"indicator\":\"ClassC\",\"month\":201612,\"ww\":201649,\"test_time\":47.48,\"p\":48.0,\"Product\":\"RB\"}}")
```

Comment: where should I include this?Sorry because I really new to programming

Comment: add this to the series -> data

Comment: I think you need to parse the data in another format. Can you please share which value is the x and y axis from the ["index", "indicator", "month", "ww", "test_time", "p", "Product"]

Comment: y axis is number range; x axis is month

Comment: which is the number range from the object is it index

Comment: var datas = JSON.parse(data)
    var myArray = [];
    for(var i in datas ) {
        myArray.push(datas[i]);
    }
    var mydata = myArray.map(i=>([i.month,i.p]));

Answer (score 0):

[Js fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/Kondaldurgam/bofzwhzn/1/)

Add your JSON file in series

```
             Highcharts.chart('container', {

          title: {
              text: 'Solar Employment Growth by Sector, 2010-2016'
          },

          subtitle: {
              text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
          },

          yAxis: {
              title: {
                  text: 'Number of Employees'
              }
          },
          legend: {
              layout: 'vertical',
              align: 'right',
              verticalAlign: 'middle'
          },

          plotOptions: {
              series: {
                  pointStart: 2010
              }
          },

          series: [{
              name: 'Installation',
              data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
          }, {
              name: 'Manufacturing',
              data: [24916, 24064, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 40434]
          }, {
              name: 'Sales & Distribution',
              data: [11744, 17722, 16005, 19771, 20185, 24377, 32147, 39387]
          }, {
              name: 'Project Development',
              data: [null, null, 7988, 12169, 15112, 22452, 34400, 34227]
          }, {
              name: 'Other',
              data: [12908, 5948, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 18111]
          }]

      });
```