# How to build a highchart with external json file?

Tags: javascript, html, json, highcharts

Anyone can share a basic highchart code here that the data from external json file?

I try to read all the material that related to my post but I still not able create the high chart by using **getJSON**, hope that anyone can share me your idea here, thanks.

This is some part of my json file:

```
  [
     {
         "indicator": "ClassC",
         "month": 201611,
         "ww": 201648,
         "test_time": 0.0,
         "p": 48.0,
         "Product": "RB"
     },
     {
         "indicator": "ClassC",
         "month": 201612,
         "ww": 201649,
         "test_time": 47.48,
         "p": 48.0,
         "Product": "RB"
     },
     ...
 ]
```

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43749836/how-to-extract-data-fron-json-to-javascript-highchart ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract data fron json to javascript highchart?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43749836/how-to-extract-data-fron-json-to-javascript-highchart)

Answer (score 0):

Just check this fiddle. As you may find the answer is here

https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/

and also check the api used there. you can find the json format which is returned

```
https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?.
```

Updated Code

```
$.getJSON('your url', function (data) {
var datas = JSON.parse(data)
var myArray = [];
for(var i in datas ) {
    myArray.push(datas[i]);
}
var mydata = myArray.map(i=>([i.month,i.p]));

    // Create the chart
    Highcharts.stockChart('container', {


        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
        },

        title: {
            text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'AAPL',
            data: mydata,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

the var datas section should be replaced by the data from the $.getJson

Comment: yes I read this and now my code actually copy from this website, the json file I have also same as this format, but my problem now is once I used getJSON to read the json file and my title of the chart need based on data in json , start from here I not able to view any graph and I did not get any error too... I really don't know how I going to insert getJSON

Comment: can you please post the sample json format which you are recieved from getjson?

Comment: I have added above

Comment: actually the data format should be like  [
[1273017600000,36.57],
[1273104000000,35.18],
[1273190400000,33.69],]

[[x1,y1],[x2,y2]]

so you need to convert your json data like this from server side or in script

Comment: I try to convert from pandas dataframe actually, and I not able to convert the format as you show me

Comment: Okay let me check and I will give you the array values

Comment: I have update the answer just check if it is working . I tested with the sample you provided in a fiddle and it seems to be working

Comment: var mydata = myArray.map(i=>([i.month,i.p]));
Hello, sorry may I know what is this line mean?

Comment: It will convert you data from json to the format which hightcharts required to show data as [[x1,y1],[x2,y2]]

Comment: but my data in json is something like name:a, age:1 City:SG;name:b, age:6 City:SG

Comment: and if I need to put it hight chart I need to filter again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143241/discussion-between-nair-athul-and-shi-jie-tio).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code for highchart(bubble chart and guage chart) from external data

### HTML & JAVASCRIPT

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<style>
.highcharts-point-select{
stroke: orange;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-6" id="container1"></div>
<div class="col-md-6" id="container2"></div>
</div>
<script>
$.getJSON(
    'http://localhost/highcharts/bubble-chart/bubblechart.json',
     function (data) {
Highcharts.chart('container1', {
    chart: {
        type: 'bubble',
        plotBorderWidth: 1,
        zoomType: 'xy'
    },

   xAxis: {
        gridLineWidth: 1
    },

     plotOptions: {
        series: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            marker: {
                states: {
                    select: {
                        fillColor : 'orange'

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
   yAxis: {
        startOnTick: false,
        endOnTick: false
    },


    series: [{
       data: data,
        color: 'green',
    }   ]

});

Highcharts.chart('container2', {

    chart: {
        type: 'gauge',
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBackgroundImage: null,
        plotBorderWidth: 0,
        plotShadow: false
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Speedometer'
    },

    pane: {
        startAngle: -150,
        endAngle: 150,
        background: [{
            backgroundColor: {
                linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                stops: [
                    [0, '#FFF'],
                    [1, '#333']
                ]
            },
            borderWidth: 0,
            outerRadius: '109%'
        }, {
            backgroundColor: {
                linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                stops: [
                    [0, '#333'],
                    [1, '#FFF']
                ]
            },
            borderWidth: 1,
            outerRadius: '107%'
        }, {
            // default background
        }, {
            backgroundColor: '#DDD',
            borderWidth: 0,
            outerRadius: '105%',
            innerRadius: '103%'
        }]
    },

    // the value axis
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 200,

        minorTickInterval: 'auto',
        minorTickWidth: 1,
        minorTickLength: 10,
        minorTickPosition: 'inside',
        minorTickColor: '#666',

        tickPixelInterval: 30,
        tickWidth: 2,
        tickPosition: 'inside',
        tickLength: 10,
        tickColor: '#666',
        labels: {
            step: 2,
            rotation: 'auto'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'km/h'
        },
        plotBands: [{
            from: 0,
            to: 120,
            color: '#55BF3B' // green
        }, {
            from: 120,
            to: 160,
            color: '#DDDF0D' // yellow
        }, {
            from: 160,
            to: 200,
            color: '#DF5353' // red
        }]
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Speed',
        data: data[7],
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' km/h'
        }
    }]

},
// Add some life
function (chart) {
    if (!chart.renderer.forExport) {
        setInterval(function () {
            var point = chart.series[0].points[0],
                newVal,
                inc = Math.round((Math.random() - 0.5) * 20);

            newVal = point.y + inc;
            if (newVal < 0 || newVal > 200) {
                newVal = point.y - inc;
            }

            point.update(newVal);

        }, 3000);
    }
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

### bubblechart.JSON

```
[
    [9, 81, 103],
    [98, 5, 89],
    [51, 50, 73],
    [41, 22, 14],
    [58, 24, 20],
    [78, 37, 34],
    [55, 56, 53],
    [91]

]
```