# How to plot highcharts basic line with external json?

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

Anyone can help me edit this

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

title: {
    text: 'Solar Employment Growth by Sector, 2010-2016'
},

subtitle: {
    text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
},

yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: 'Number of Employees'
    }
},
legend: {
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'middle'
},

plotOptions: {
    series: {
        pointStart: 2010
    }
},

series: [{
    name: 'Installation',
    data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
}, {
    name: 'Manufacturing',
    data: [24916, 24064, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 40434]
}, {
    name: 'Sales & Distribution',
    data: [11744, 17722, 16005, 19771, 20185, 24377, 32147, 39387]
}, {
    name: 'Project Development',
    data: [null, null, 7988, 12169, 15112, 22452, 34400, 34227]
}, {
    name: 'Other',
    data: [12908, 5948, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 18111]
}]
});
```

so that **$getJSON** was used and data are from external json file, I have trouble this for few months and I not able to do it also event thought I get some advise from here [How to extract data fron json to javascript highchart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43749836/how-to-extract-data-fron-json-to-javascript-highchart) yesterday and try it in sleepless night...

Comment: What is the source of the json? What is the structure of the json? You need to put the url in gejson function and the in callback create a chart - http://jsfiddle.net/k8fa7v8q/ See the last paragraph https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/custom-preprocessing